# Spinnaker not automatically building pipeline

Tags: spinnaker

I am following this tutorial. Everything works, just not the automatically build:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-spinnaker-kubernetes-engine

I can see that when I look at the Automated triggers, it starts with this:

[image]

But then it refreshes it self(The two circular arrows), and then it shows this:

[image]

Du you know if the tutorial sample is still working, or do you know why it is not building automatically(if something is missing in the tutorial)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried that tutorial in particular, but just yesterday I worked through a very similar tutorial on Spinnaker's own website, and it worked flawlessly from start to finish. It also seems much easier to set up than the one you linked, with very little command line. You can find it here:

https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/tutorials/codelabs/gcp-kubernetes-source-to-prod/

The only part that tripped me up was SSH'ing into the Spinnaker instance to make it accessible over localhost - the provided command didn't work unless I made it all one line, so just keep an eye out for that when you get to it.